# Does a move html entity exist

Tags: html, entity

I'm looking for an html entity code for a move symbol (with left right up down arrows). The same one that appears after `cursor: move;` is applied in css. Does anyone know if this is possible? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: cursors MAY have matching glyphs in a font, but not likely. Use something like windows charmap to see what's available.

Comment: Note that (for example) in Ubuntu the cursor becomes a fist (when `cursor:move;` is used).

Comment: Wasn't aware of that. Worth thinking about for future reference, thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest I found was this ✥ (`&#10021;` or `&#x2725;`).

Answer (score 5):

`&#10021;` ✥

`&#x2725;` ✥

`&#10149;`➥

`&#9735;` ☇

`&uarr;&darr;` ↑↓

`&rlarr;` ⇄

As mentioned in the other answers, there is no exact match. Here are some that might be close enough for some.

Answer (score 3):

↔ (`&harr;` or `&#8596;`) and ↕ (`&varr;` or `&#8597;`) are available, however there is no up/down/left/right arrow symbol in the [arrow subgroup](http://utf8-characters.com/arrows/).

Comment: Ah, shame. Never mind, I've ended up just settling for `&uarr;&darr;` next to each other which looks good. Since the option is essentially moving items up and down a list anyway this is fine. Thanks.

Comment: The `&harr;` entity is defined in HTML 4.01, but the `&varr;` entity is an HTML5 novelty with essentially more limited browser support.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such entity, and there is even no character like that. In interesting way to check whether the symbol you are looking for exists as a character is to visit http://shapecatcher.com/ and draw it. It’s not exact science, of course.

It is generally pointless to look for HTML entity codes. Those codes add nothing to the expressive power of the language: you can use character references `&#...` instead, or enter the characters directly if you are using UTF-8, as you normally should. The real question, after identifying a character, is whether it is supported in fonts and what to do about this. Whether there is an HTML entity for it is really irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

To [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#named-character-references)! Check out table 8.5, "named character references". A quick search of the word "arrow" doesn't turn up exactly what you're looking for but with over 2200 named entities, maybe you can find something that looks "close enough".

Comment: The HTML5 draft is not a specification. It says itself: “This is a draft document and may be updated, replaced or obsoleted by other documents at any time. It is inappropriate to cite this document as other than work in progress.”In particular, it adds a large number of entities, which are *not* supported except in fairly new browsers.

Comment: Oh good grief go take a walk outside dude. If it works for someone's use case then it's still a good reference. No one waits for those things to become "official", which is why browser progress takes place more often than every 10 years.

Comment: @Toby, it simply does not work. Try testing the added entities on some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I made a pen for this purpose, feel free to use it : [Create a Move cursor with html + css](https://codepen.io/migli/pen/yeQLBX)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="cp-drag">
    </div>
</div>
// see codepen for css please
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to the same conclusion, no easy character, but my fix was to create a div with both the up/down arrow and side/side arrow in the same space. A bit finicky, but if you had to have it...

```
<div style="font-size:200%;display:inline-block;position:relative;top:-11px;left:-15px;">
    <div style="display:inline-block;">&#8596;</div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;left:-32px;position:relative;">&#8597;</div>
</div>
```